# Change background color for a specific <tr> in AngularJS using ng-repeat depending on database values

Tags: php, html, css, angularjs

I wanted to change background colors of specific tr depending on the database values that it returns:

> html file

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit" ng-class="{'D6-class': data.Dag === '6', 'D7-class': data.Dag === '7', 'P2-class': data.Periode === '2' && (data.Dag=='1' || data.Dag =='2' || data.Dag=='4' || data.Dag =='5'), 'D3-class': data.Periode === '2' && data.Dag =='3', 'P3-class': data.Periode === '3' && (data.Dag=='1' || data.Dag =='2'|| data.Dag=='3' || data.Dag=='4' || data.Dag =='5'), 'P4-class': data.Periode === '4' && (data.Dag=='1' || data.Dag =='2'|| data.Dag=='3' || data.Dag=='4' || data.Dag =='5')}">
                    <td align="center">{{data.Locatie}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Periode}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Dag}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Dienst}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Delen}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Start1}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Eind1}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Start2}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Eind2}}</td>
                    <td align="center">{{data.Vanaf}}</td>
                </tr>
...
```

> CSS

```
...
 .D7-class{
  background-color: #FABEAA;
}
.D3-class{
  background-color: #FAF9AA;
}
.P2-class{
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.P3-class{
  background-color: #BEFAAA;
}
.P4-class{
  background-color: #C390D4;
}
...
```

Now the most part works great. It looks at the data it got from the database, but not every `<tr>` is changed like it should. If I select all lines for only like D3 (Yellow) it shows 1 line yellow and other one white. Is there a way to avoid this? All rows should be yellow.

[image]

Comment: It looks like problem is in data. Do you also set data.Periode = '2' ? Debug data source, add to row values {{data.Periode === '2' && data.Dag =='3'}}  {{data.Periode}} {{data.Dag}} {{data.Periode === '2'}} {{data.Dag =='3'}} and check them...

Comment: The data itself (coming from database) isn't the problem. The Second col on the photo is the 'Periode', the 3 col is the 'Dag'. Filtering them gives the right result. Except the colors that take one row and other not is the strange part. I don't see anything that points to it.

Comment: Did you check styles that applied(source code debuggers in browser)? If everithing fine with data, then problem should be with styles.

Comment: Try to inspect element and see wich div/class is making them an other color

Comment: Thanks guys. Found a different class in the css file. Using the first class will give the first row a certain color (gray) and the second one white. I just changed the css class.